# Remove PDF Layer(s) from PDF Using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Is the subject possible? I've looked over the documentation and cannot determine with certainty if it is. I have a PDF with a layer list that looks like the picture. I'd like to take the layers that are turned off entirely out of the PDF so that other code that I have working can convert the PDF to TIFF. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: How easy it is probably depends on how the layers were done.  If it is an array of content dicts, it is probably easy to remove some of them.  Otherwise, you need to parse into the content dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/92) (open as of 21 sept 2015), optional content groups (which are [called layers](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6431) in Acrobat) are not yet supported in PyPDF2.

Comment: Have there been any changes to this since?

Comment: @SaleemKhan The issue is still open, but seems unchanged since 2015. A quick look at the commits since that time doesn't show anything obvious related to this. So the answer's probably no.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280714/remove-image-layer-from-geospatial-pdf-using-ogr2ogr) for approaches on how to do this for the specific case that motivated this question - removing the orthoimage from a USGS topo map.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude one or more PDF layers and convert to TIFF in one go using `gdal_translate` with the flag `--config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS_OFF`. [See this page for an example](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html).

I have applied this specifically for manipulating USGS topo maps which come as geospatial PDFs.