# When saving PDF via PyPDF2 it's making hidden layers visible

Tags: python, django, ghostscript, pypdf

while saving via PDFFileWriter() of PyPDF2 the output file has all previously hidden layers visible. Is there a possibility to delete them from file or at least still hide them?

```
with open(self.file.path,"rb") as f:
   inputpdf = PdfFileReader(f)
   output = PdfFileWriter()
   output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(pagenumber))
   output.write(outputStream)
```

Otherwise, is there another library which supports hidden layers?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you there is a way to solve it with pyPDF2 can do that, it cannot remove or hide layers. you  can check out this post for more:

[Remove PDF Layer(s) from PDF Using PyPDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703866/remove-pdf-layers-from-pdf-using-pypdf2)

Im not sure if there are any alternatives